# How can i pass content inside a textarea in a form to another form in same page without submit button

Tags: php, html, forms

Here am working on a page were i need the content inside a textarea in a form tag to be passed to another set of form tag in the same page were i have no submit button to pass the content, please help me on this and pardon me if went wrong somewhere, thank you.

**content.php**

```
<?php
echo'
<form>
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group"><textarea rows="6" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mail body" name="mail_body"></textarea></div>
//Without using submit button
</form>';
?>
```

**pass_content.php**

```
<?php
<form>
//pass the the content in above textarea in this form which is on the same page
</form>
?>
```

Comment: using jquery its possibe. Just add one key up event to textarea . In that function copy the message from first textarea to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using jquery. Like this :

```js
var $mail = $(".mail");

$(".email").keyup(function() {
    $mail.val( this.value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group"><textarea rows="6" type="text" class="form-control email" placeholder="Mail body" name="mail_body"></textarea></div>
</form>

<form>
<textarea rows="6" type="text" class="form-control mail" ></textarea>
</form>
```

**UPDATE :** As you want another field to be hidden.

you jquery code:

```
var $mail = $(".mail");

$(".email").keyup(function() {
   $mail.val( this.value );
});
```

and here is your html code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form> 
  <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
    <textarea rows="6" type="text" class="form-control email" placeholder="Mail body" name="mail_body"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>

<form>
  <input type="hidden" class="mail" >
</form>
```

Comment: One doubt sir.. can i make the textarea inside the second form a hidden field with value as content typed in textarea inside first form tag-set?

Comment: Yes you can. It doesn't matter the field is hidden or not you can pass values to it.

Comment: But sir what should i specify in <input type="hidden" value="??"> can i get some help?

Comment: soo..no need of specifying value to it??

Comment: No. it will get dynamic value from the first textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Check this -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            console.log('document loaded');

            $( "#box-texarea" ).keyup(function() {
                console.log( "Handler for .keyup() called." );

                // Get data from textarea
                var userData = $(this).val();
                console.log('userData : '+userData);

                // Place data inside form
                $('#fm-userdata').html(userData);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea placeholder="Place for textarea" id="box-texarea" style="width:500px; height: 100px;"></textarea>

    <br>
    <form id="fm-userdata" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can i pass it as a hidden field in second form tag?

Comment: What do u mean by hidden field ?

Comment: I mean to say that, the content inside the textarea i want to pass that content as value of hidden field inside the form tag-set

Comment: Of course you can do that also . Here is an example - ```var hiddenForm = '<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="'+userData+'">'; $('#fm-userdata').html(hiddenForm);```